How to make antlr4 skip the intermediate errors and continue parsing backward when parsing Sql?
I want to use antlr4 to separate a batch of Sql independently one by one, but if there is a syntax error in a certain Sql, all the Sql after this error will not be parsed correctly.
If I have the following SQL statements:
SELECT
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

It is clear that the first SELECT is an incomplete or invalid statement. How can I configure ANTLR 4 to skip over this bad statement and correctly parse the subsequent valid statements?
Should I develop a detailed error response strategy or modify the grammar file?

That is the million dollar question! This is a very hard problem to solve in general

yeah, i think it is million dollar question too
